# Como faço para manipular o JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog Java pelo teclado?

Tags: java, teclado, aplicação-desktop

Eu criei um sistema PDV para um cliente, só que ele não gostou de usar mouse na hora de finalizar venda, porque perde muito tempo. Então fui atrás de vários tutoriais e fóruns, mas não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar com esse problema.

**Essa é uma parte do meu código (que está 100% funcionando). Só que eu gostaria de usar somente o teclado para escolher uma das opções (sem ajuda do mouse):**

```
int resposta =   JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Deseja imprimir cupom?", "Confirmar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

 if(resposta==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
     imprimirCupomTickets(listaModelVendaProdutoTickets, modelVendaTickets);
     int codCli = Integer.parseInt(tfUsuarioID.getText());      
     limparFormulario(); 
     }

 else if(resposta==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
 int codCli = Integer.parseInt(tfUsuarioID.getText());      
 limparFormulario();       
 }

 else if(resposta==JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION){
 int codCli = Integer.parseInt(tfUsuarioID.getText());      
 limparFormulario();    
 }
```